# Zend Studio Hybrid Mobile Project

Tags: hybrid-mobile-app, zend-studio

I want to start Hybrid Mobile Project in Zend studio.

According to zend official documentation (http://files.zend.com/help/Zend-Studio-13/content/creating_a_new_hybrid_mobile_project.htm) creating Hybrid Mobile (Cordova) Application Project can be accessed through:

"**New > Project > Hybrid Mobile (Cordova) Application Project.** ",but my zend studio doesn't have such item.

[my zend studio screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eWrrf.jpg)

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Zend has Discontinued mobile application features from Zend Studio 13.6 onwards. 
If you are not using Zend Studio 13.6, let me know the version that you are using. 
http://www.zend.com/studio/zend-studio-13.6.0-release-notes.txt

However; you can still install 3rd party plug-ins (for example, THyM) in Zend Studio (Help | Eclipse Marketplace) and work with it.

https://blogs.sap.com/2015/07/04/create-a-simple-hybrid-app-with-eclipse-thym-and-openui5/